# how to change payment date in Azure?

Tags: azure, billing

It looks like it costs 8 days per month in Azure. How do I change my billing date? What permissions do I need to change the payment date?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because customer support questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's an API that will let you change the billing date on your Azure Subscription.

Your best bet would be to open a billing support ticket (which is free). Support team may be able to help you out with this if it is possible to change the billing date.